# Show Dialog over MDI Container

Tags: vb.net, dialog, mdi

I have a MDI Container as startup form and in the Private Sub frmMain_Load function I want to load up frmLogin as a dialog. I did it as *frmLogin.Show()* but then the MDI Container is not on the background. When I do it as *frmLogin.ShowDialog()* then the MDI Container is loaded and frmLogin is loaded too but on the background.

Is there any solution. I tried google but I have no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set frmMain's property mdiContainer to true.
 
`IsMdiContainer=true` 
 and
`frmLogin.MdiParent = Me` in your function

Comment: I don't want it to be inside the MDI Container but outside of it. Like on top of the screen. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RicardoJacobs:set login form property TopMost=true & reply me

Comment: I did that and I did insert frmLogin.ShowDialog() in the frmMain.Load function but then only the login form is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the OnShown method instead:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnShown(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnShown(e)

  frmLogin.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub
```